# what to return when return type is Task<IactionResult> in .netcore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Im really confused in .Netcore what normally should return to a queue(messagebroker),I have a class

```
 public  Task<IActionResult> GetMerchantPlatform(int  merchantID) {

        try
        {
            var mrchantInfo =  dbContext.MerchantPlatforms.Where(s => s.Id == merchantID);
            return Task.FromResult(mrchantInfo);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;

         }
      }
```

it gives me an error :Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type **'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Linq.IQueryable<Models.MerchantPlatform>>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult>'**

when should i return Iactionresult?and when should i return the class?and why im getting the above error?

Comment: Unrelated, but `throw ex;` is an anti-pattern.  If you're not handling the exception in any way, just remove the try/catch entirely.  If you are handling the exception and want to re-throw it, just use `throw;`.  What you're currently doing is removing useful information from the original exception.

Comment: in catch `return=Task.FromResult(0);` I hope the code will work if you write

Comment: @EminNiftiyev: No, a syntax error is unlikely to help here.  (You can't *assign a value* to the `return` keyword.)  Additionally, the error isn't happening in the `catch` block.  Throwing an exception is always a valid exit strategy for a method.

Comment: @David thanks for the comment, I have removed it in my code,and do you have any idea regarding the return type?

Comment: Read the error message and realise that all you've got in `mrchantInfo` is an `IQueryable<T>` - you've not even caused the query to go to the database. You probably want to do something to *materialize* the result in your method, such as calling `SingleOrDefault` or `ToList`, or something similar (and indeed possible `async` variants) to get to actually having a `MerchantPlatform` or set thereof in a local variable, before you worry about returning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the `ControllerBase` class you have to return an `IActionResult` or a `Task<IActionResult>`. There are plenty of pre-defined result objects available, which you can choose from, cause the result consist of multiple information that has to be defined by you. First is the HTTP status code that should be returned and depending on that you potentially have to return a body and/or some header entries.

If your method is within a `ControllerBase` class, there are already some helper methods within this class like `Ok()`, `BadRequest()`, `Forbid()`, `NoContent()`, `NotFound()`, etc. All with several overloads, depending on their usual use case.

So in your case, you probably have to write something like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetMerchantPlatform(int  merchantID)
{
    try
    {
        var mrchantInfo = await dbContext.MerchantPlatforms
            .Where(s => s.Id == merchantID)
            .ToListAsync();

        return Ok(mrchantInfo);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex);
    }
}
```

Be aware, that the try/catch is probably not needed in every function. For this purpose you can register your self-written middleware, that can put such a block around each action and act accordingly to your needs. But that's some stuff for another question or a search for

> [asp core middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

And if you really want to only return the *content* in your method, you should consider to use the [`ApiControllerAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: thanks a lot,it works fine,regarding your second comment,self-written middleware is what?can you take an example or send me a link in this regard?

Comment: Added link to search keywords. 